# R - Remove duplicate rows based on a variable, but ignoring NA's and a few specific values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I need to remove duplicates based on the variable "e-mail". However, there's a lot of NA's there that I cannot get rid of because they're valuable observations. Besides NA's, some people happened to put a dot in it, so I want to know if I can get rid of the rows with duplicated e-mails while ignoring NA's and the observations with "." on the email.

I've tried `distinct()` and `n_distinct()` but both of these don't have a na.rm option.

Here's an example of what i mean:

```
library(dplyr)
email <- c("xxx@xxx.xxx","xxx@xxx.xxx","yyy@yyy.yyy","yyy@yyy.yyy","zzz@zzz.zzz","zzz@zzz.zzz",".",".",".",".",".")
names <- c("Gabriel","Marcos","Julio","Rafael","Victor","Azymov","Turkey Sandvich","Marzia","Door","Cato","Doggo")
test <- data.frame(email,names)
morenames <- c("Soap","Redbull","World of Warcraft")
moreemails <- c(NA,NA,NA)
test2 <- data.frame(moreemails, morenames)
names(test2) <- c("email","names")
test <- test %>% rbind(test2)
test
verif_dup <- test[duplicated(test[,1]),]
verif_dup
```

I can see all the duplicate emails on verif_dup. I want a way to remove the duplicates like xxx@xxx.xxx, yyy@yyy.yyy and zzz@zzz.zzz, but keep the "." and NA's.

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data with `dput`

Comment: This sounds like a very doable job. But I guess nobody will help unless you show at least the *kind* of data you have in more detail (because that's where the devil is, as they say)

Comment: Is there any easy tutorial on how to provide a sample of my data, other than DPut documentation?

Comment: Yeah @Gabriel, I'd just make a dataframe with the columns and some examples of what you are looking at in your data. For example: 

```number <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
string <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
data.frame(number, string)```

Then people can copy paste it into R to see what you are looking at!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've tried to put some fictional data in to see if people can help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not think of an elegant way to do this in one step. I split the operations into one data frame for isolating the NA and ".", and another for the duplicates.

```
test_missing <- test %>%
  filter(is.na(email) | email == '.')

# here I assume you keep the first row of the duplicated values (the 'names' column is different for each)
test_duprm <- test %>%
  filter(!is.na(email) & email != '.') %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)

bind_rows(test_missing, test_duprm)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Can you explain the second part to me ? I get that you're filtering for values different that NA and "." and grouping by email, but what does the filter(row_number() ==1) does? Is that an indirect way to check for duplicates?

Comment: Yes it's an indirect way to check for a duplicate. Using `group_by()` and `row_number()` together just means you are counting the row number for each email. So (as an example) the second time the email 'xxx@xxx.com' shows up, you would get the value 2. We just keep every instance where it equals 1, removing all instances where the row number is greater than 1.

Comment: Try the code `test %>% group_by(email) %>% mutate(row_number())` to see the step in between.